# How to set 'left' of an element positioned inside a dynamic element

Tags: html, css, positioning

Please take a look at the attached image, it makes it easier to understand.

In general the question is just how to absolute position an element left:100% while making it appear a bit less than 100%. Margin doesn't seem to work in absolute positioning.

I created a resizeble element with jQuery, and there is a right 'bullet' for the user to resize the element. I don't want to bullet to be on top of the container's border, so I set its position to absolute, and left: 98%.

Problem is - resizing the element takes the bullet to the left or right of the container's end, depending on its size (because the position of the bullet is set in percentages). Only 'solution' is to set its 'left' to 100%, but then the bullet is on top of the div. Adding a non breaking space after the bullet also didn't work since I had to set the left to 98% to contain both the bullet and the space.

What do you think? Is there a simple solution I didn't come up with?

Thanks in advance,
Omer[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iliKO.png)

Edit: Jila here offered a simple solution of using calc:

```
#myContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bullet-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% - 16px);
    margin-right: 10px;
    top: 40%;
    color: blue;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

I tried 100% - 10px without the calc before and it didn't work obviously
Hope it can help others and thanks Jila

Comment: Hai, You much add your code to check further

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  Post some code so we know you have done something at least

Answer (score 0):

**[`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)** only works on a **[positioned element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**. That is to say, any element that does not have the default `static` positioning. In addition to this, you should never set `left: 98%`; you should set `right: 2%` to prevent any confusion.

If you want to set a left offset on a dynamic element, you're looking for **[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left)**.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
}

input {
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I do want it to be absolute positioned. Then margin won't work anymore, and setting it to 4% right, will make its distance dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

> how to absolute position an element left:100% while making it appear a bit less than 100%.

Don't use `left: 98%;`. Use `right: --;`. Since, as you state, percentages are dynamic, decide on a fixed value for the element offset. For example if you choose 10px the element on the right would be `right: 10px` and the element on the left would be `left: 10px;`.

If you really really want to use `left` for the one on the right use `left: calc(100%-10px);`, but there's no real reason for doing that when you can use `right`.

Comment: Hey Jila thanks for your answer, calc is exactly what I was looking for thanks!